# Cannot touch a external view from inside a AsyncTask... but not always

Tags: android

I have made an AsyncTask that should compile a TextView. This is very short recap of what I did. I deleted a lot of lines so I hope I didn't forget anything.

```
public class MyClass extends RelativeLayout {
        private TextView messageTextView;


    public MyClass(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context); }
    public MyClass(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init(context); }
    public MyClass(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context); }


    private void init(Context context) {
        createLayoutContent();
                run();
    }

    private void createLayoutContent (Context context) {
        this.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 0));

        messageView = new TextView(context);
        messageView.setText("test");
        this.addView(messageView);
    }

    private void start() {
        new AsyncTask<Void, String, Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                try {
                    String s_message = "test2";
                    messageView.setText(s_message);    **// HERE IS WHERE THE ERROR IS //**
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            }
        }.execute();

    }

}
```

After this, I put the object directly in the layout:

```
    <<...>MyClass
        android:id="@+id/test"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    />
```

Now the problem is that on **some** apps this perfectly works. As soon as the Activity runs, setContentView() creates the ui objects and everything is fine.
On **other** apps, I continuously receive an error that says that "*only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.*"

I get this error, but I don't get why on some apps it works fine...
Even more weird, it happened me once that the app on which generally gave error, suddenly started working and then went back to the error after two correct runs!!

This it totally weird.

I know that maybe the details are not enough to detect the error, so excuse me for this, but I checked all the detais I could think at and I could not find notable differences between when it works and when not. Maybe more expert eyes can detect something, explain something or suggest me where to debug.
Can some one help me?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure, why it works some times. But it should fail every time.
May be it works, if the Android system decides to run your background thread code within the UI thread.

Here is what fixes your problem:
Move the "touch views" things to `onPostExcution()` or `onProgressUpdate()`.
UI is meant to be touched only from within the UI thread. AsyncTask helps to do this quite conveniently. All `AsyncTask's` methods but `doInBackground()` are running on UI thread.

So, **never** change `Views` directly from `doInBackground()`.

```
private void start() {
    new AsyncTask<Void, String, String>() {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                String s_message = "test2";
                return s_message;
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            messageView.setText(s);
        }
    }.execute();
}
```

Comment: Ooooh!! onPostExecute saved my day! Thank you.
About why it worked... I don't know, but I'm sure it works on a few apps that currently are online in the market... just to be sure I will edit them all anyway.

Comment: Any method but `doInBackground()`. Because this method is running in background thread.